# Unable to display table in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

My friend and I are new to shiny.

We're trying to self-learn shiny. Everything is fine except a big and a small questions.

The big question is: why can't we display table with `renderTable()`? We can only display the year range.

The small question is: can we display the sidebar labels in the correlation plot instead of the labels assigned in the csv?

Many thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel
  (
    checkboxGroupInput(
      "feature",
      "Feature",
      c(
        "No of case" = "no_case",
        "Minor Case" = "minor_case",
        "All Non Fatal Case" = "all_non_fatl",
        "Fatal Case" = "fatal_case"
      )
    ),
    sliderInput(
      "year",
      "Year",
      min = 2015,
      max = 2021,
      value = c(2015, 2021)
    )
  ),
  
  mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("correlation_plot")),
    tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("ecd"))
  ))
))



server <- function(input, output) {
  yearrange <- reactive({
    input$year[1]:input$year[2]
  })
  output$correlation_plot <- renderPlot({
    validate(need(input$feature, 'Check one of these items.'))
    plot(ecd$year,
         ecd[[input$feature]],
         xlab = "Year",
         ylab = input$feature) #how not to show tab name but show the side bar name
  })
  output$ecd <- renderTable({
    yearrange()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shared the data (`ecd`) so I cannot test it but you can try this.

**For the big question**

Shiny displays what you tell it to display. In the `reactive` function you have used  `input$year[1]:input$year[2]` so it displays a sequence from the starting slider value to ending slider value. I am guessing this but I think `ecd` data has a column called `year` (or something else) which has year value. You can use `subset` (or `filter` in `dplyr`) to subset the data for those specific years in the data.

**For small question**

Create a named vector (`vec`) so you can easily use it in `checkboxGroupInput` as well as use it in `ylab` to name the Y-axis.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

c(
  "No of case" = "no_case",
  "Minor Case" = "minor_case",
  "All Non Fatal Case" = "all_non_fatl",
  "Fatal Case" = "fatal_case"
) -> vec

ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel
  (
    checkboxGroupInput(
      "feature",
      "Feature",
      vec
    ),
    sliderInput(
      "year",
      "Year",
      min = 2015,
      max = 2021,
      value = c(2015, 2021)
    )
  ),
  
  mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("correlation_plot")),
    tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("ecd"))
  ))
))



server <- function(input, output) {
  yearrange <- reactive({
    subset(ecd, year %in% input$year[1]:input$year[2])
  })
  
  output$correlation_plot <- renderPlot({
    validate(need(input$feature, 'Check one of these items.'))
    plot(ecd$year,
         ecd[[input$feature]],
         xlab = "Year",
         ylab = names(vec[vec == input$feature])) 
  })
  output$ecd <- renderTable({
    yearrange()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: It works for the table tab! Thanks first! Let me digest it for a moment. Will ask you for further guidance from your code. :)